# Using a multi-dimensional form to insert data in access

Tags: ms-access, crosstab

I'm having a rough time creating an ms-access form for my client.

Here's the thing: every 3-4 years, my client receives a `.pdf` from the government and needs to insert that data into their database.

http://www.ntf.be/sites/default/files/media/coeffermageofficiels2011.pdf

This sheet gives, for a given period of time, per province and per geographic type, the value of the multiplier to apply to housings and agriculture rents. (hope this makes sense to you)

So a multiplier depends on 4 things: Date, Province, Geo Type and Rent Type

I have several tables:

- Provinces (PK: Province ID)
- Geo Types (PK: Geo Type ID)
- Rent Types (PK: Rent Type ID)
- Multipliers (PK: Multiplier ID, FK: Province ID, FK: Geo ID, FK: Rent ID, Multiplier Value, Effective Date)

What my client wants is a form that mimics this exact PDF, so that he can easily fill in the data whenever he gets the new multiplier values.

After unsuccessfully trying to use a crosstab query, and nested continuous forms to reproduce this, I can't think of a better solution to make a hard-coded form that will then perform all the inserts with hard-coded VB queries...

While I know how I could hard-code all this, I really wonder if there isn't another solution.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a "continuous forms" form that was bound to a temporary table with columns corresponding to those in the PDF file. The setup code (e.g., in Form Load, perhaps) could populate the temporary table with the required records for each Province/Region, and if the rates for the previous period were already in the database then it could plug in those values as well. The "Augm. %" fields could be calculated on-the-fly and serve as a visual data-entry validation check.

When the user had "filled in the blanks" then a "Save" button on the form header could use two Append queries to copy the new data into the appropriate tables: one for "Terres" and one for "Batiments".

Comment: Oh I never thought of using a dummy table. Will look into implementing it.
However, "terres" and "batiments" are not tables, they are a type of multiplier (defined in rent types table).
In the PDF, one line in the table actually results in two lines in the "multipliers" table.
I'll try all this out then. :-) and thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: The one small thing that annoys me is that the "province" name keeps repeating in the continuous form.
Is there a quick way to set a field to be invisible if the previous row contained the same value for that field?

Comment: @user1747281 Sorry, no. There is a `Hide Duplicates` setting for text boxes in Reports, but not for text boxes in Forms.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple more options you could consider.

**Option 1:**
When I create forms I don't usually like them to be directly editable, at least not without some validation\user confirmation.
You could:

- Set up the relevant queries to get the data into the pdf format.
- Create a form based on these queries
- When the user wants to edit\add data, put an event on the field (i.e. double click event) which could open a seperate little form or input box.
- Allow them to input a new value and when they click ok, use a sub-procedure to lookup and write that new value to the relevant table\field.
- Then, use the form repaint\requery so the user can directly see their update.

**Option 2:**
A different approach but maybe simpler and more flexible.
Create an Access report which replilcates the pdf.
This will look just as good as the pdf.

- You could have a single input form (based on your own structure and not the pdf) where the user can input data
- When they want to see the result, you could give them a command button which opens the report.
- They could also print it out.